# Why doesn't animate inside a linearGradient referenced by another linearGradient work?

Tags: svg, svg-animate

Sample SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="140" height="140">
<linearGradient id="reuseme" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" spreadMethod="reflect">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="black"/>
    <animate attributeName="y1" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="0%;150%;0%"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="a" x1="22.677" x2="132.625" y1="338.835" y2="338.835" href="#reuseme"/>
<rect fill="url(#a)" x="10" y="10" width="130" height="130"/>
</svg>
```

Why can't I use `<animate>` within my reusable `<linearGradient id="reuseme">` above? When I try, the animation does not play. If I move the `<animate>` tag to the bottom `<linearGradient id="a">` it works:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="140" height="140">
<linearGradient id="reuseme" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" spreadMethod="reflect">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="black"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="a" x1="22.677" x2="132.625" y1="338.835" y2="338.835" href="#reuseme">
    <animate attributeName="y1" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="0%;150%;0%"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect fill="url(#a)" x="10" y="10" width="130" height="130"/>
</svg>
```

The reason I want to do this is because I have lots of shapes that use the same gradient and the same animation. It stands to reason if I can reuse a gradient, I should be able to reuse its animation too. I have also tried `<use>` and `<animate href="#foo">` to try to achieve the same thing but failed miserably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're setting y1 in the gradient with id="a" and that overrides any setting in id="reuseme".

Any properties/attributes/stops are used from the first gradient that's encountered with that property/attribute or stops in the reference chain.

I've removed y1 from id="a" below so the other gradient now animated because its y1 is not overridden any more.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="140" height="140">
<linearGradient id="reuseme" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" spreadMethod="reflect">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="black"/>
    <animate attributeName="y1" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="0%;150%;0%"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="a" x1="22.677" x2="132.625" y2="338.835" href="#reuseme">
    <!-- moving <animate/> here does work -->
</linearGradient>
<rect fill="url(#a)" x="10" y="10" width="130" height="130"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Interestingly, this does not work on iOS Chrome or Safari, but my second example does.

Comment: iOS Chrome is Safari inasmuch as all browsers on iOS are webkit.

Comment: I think adding y1="0" and y2="0" to the reusable gradient fixes it.

Comment: you shouldn't have to do that 0% is the default and 0% is the same as 0. You could raise a [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/)